# I'm getting error in onAppearing in my class.xaml.cs(xamarin forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The idea should be, when `onAppearing`, I will get all the information from 
`App.Database.GetInfoesAsync()`.

class.xaml.cs

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    Infolistview.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetInfoesAsync();
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).

Comment: An unhandled exception occured.

Comment: can you add a try/catch to your code?

Comment: ya, i think so. but i dont know how to.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `async void` on anything except event handlers. `OnAppearing` is not an event handler. However the `Appearing` event is raised after the framework invokes `OnAppearing`, which means you can subscribe to the event there and perform your async operations in the actual event handler for that event.

```
protected override void OnAppearing() {
    this.Appearing += Page_Appearing; //Subscribe to event
    base.OnAppearing();
}

protected async void Page_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    if(App.Database != null) {
        Infolistview.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetInfoesAsync();
    }
    //this.Appearing -= Page_Appearing; //Unsubscribe (OPTIONAL but advised)
}
```

In your example the `async void` caused any exceptions to you encountered to be swallowed as `async void` are fire and forget.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: same error happened sir. i think i need to catch the event if the database is null and make it proceed even if null but i dont know how to cos im still a beginner. deng

Comment: @KurtRuzell proceeding if null will only yield you a null reference error. Debug you code step by step to narrow down exactly where the error is being thrown.